# Swagger UI issue when having same root context for two different applications

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui, springdoc-ui

Getting swagger UI issue when two different microservice having same application root context deployed on sandbox environment.
we are using ngnix as reverse proxy routing server between client and backend server.
So from Ngnix we are unable to redirect to particular application for opening swagger page.

```
Below are configurations of my first microservice application:    

Application.properties file config:    


#Server configuration    

server.port = ${SERVER_PORT:8080}     
server.servlet.context-path=${SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH:/api}    

#spring-doc Configurations    

springdoc.api-docs.path=${SWAGGER_API_DOCS_PATH:/api-docs}     
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=${SWAGGER_UI_PATH:/}     
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=${SWAGGER_UI_ENABLED:true}      
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter=${SWAGGER_UI_FILTER:true}    


Version-1 controller file config:    

@RestController(value = "AccountControllerV1")      
@RequestMapping("/v1/account")    
public class AccountController {    
  rest api endpoints here    
}    


Version-2 controller file config:    

@RestController(value = "AccountControllerV2")      
@RequestMapping("/v2/account")    
public class AccountController {    
  rest api endpoints here    
}    

Below are configurations of my second microservice application:

Application.properties file config:

#Server configuration

server.port = ${SERVER_PORT:8080}  
server.servlet.context-path=${SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH:/api}

#spring-doc Configurations

springdoc.api-docs.path = ${SWAGGER_API_DOCS_PATH:/api-docs}  
springdoc.swagger-ui.path = ${SWAGGER_UI_PATH:/}  
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled = ${SWAGGER_UI_ENABLED:true}  
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter = ${SWAGGER_UI_FILTER:true}  


Version-1 controller file config:


@RestController(value = "CartControllerV1")  
@RequestMapping("/v1/cart")  
public class CartController {
  rest api endpoints here
}


Version-2 controller file config:


@RestController(value = "CartControllerV1")  
@RequestMapping("/v2/cart")  
public class CartController {
   rest api endpoints here
}

Below are the configuration of my ngnix config file for reverse routing the request to dedicate application server:

location /api/.*/account {  
proxy_pass http://account:8080;  
proxy_set_header Host $host;  
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  
}  
location /api/.*/cart {  
proxy_pass http://cart:8080;  
proxy_set_header Host $host;  
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  
}
```